# How to use cmd to move files out of redundant subfolder?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, file-management, recursive

I have a large number of textfiles that are nested in subdirectories like this:

```
D:\datafiles_01\01_data\data\{bunchoftextfiles}
               \...                
               \42_data\{bunchoftextfiles}                
               \...
               \99_data\data\{bunchoftextfiles}
D:\datafiles_02\...
D:\datafiles_99\...
```

I want to remove all the unnecessary "data" folders. However, sometimes the folder is already removed (example 42).

I found this example that does what I want, but only if executed in one of the datafiles_* directories:

```
for /D %i in (.\*) do @move %i\data\* %i\
```

How can this be adopted to run through all of the directories?

Comment: Check the filepath for '\data\' substring presence. I.e. divide it by slash as a delimiter (FOR /F) and check pre-last variable if it is `data`. But I'd recommend to use forfiles for this operation.

Comment: Try this: `for /D %J in ("D:\datafiles_*") do for /D %I in ("%~J\*_data") do (for %H in ("%~I\data\*.txt") do move "%~H" "%~I\%~nxH") & rd "%~I\data"` (the `rd` command removes empty `data` directories); but what should happen in case a file in `data` has got the same name as one in the parent directory?